# Condition in ng-if becomes false after variable in it changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm making a question editor and I have a page, where current question and its' answers are printed. There are 3 types of questions, so, I need different fields for different types.

On editor's page there is a `Select` (for type changing) and then there is  ion-list with answers. Each answer is an `ion-item` with a label with `ng-if` (tried `ng-show` too), based on selected question type. Types are got from mySQL DB firstly.

Problem is, the page after init shows all fields correctly, but when I change the type of question, all I see is fields without `ng-if`. I tried to reload the view, setting ng-change on Select (function with `$state.reload`), but it doesn't help.
And now the code:

Select:

```
<select 
      ng-model="question.type" ng-options="type.id for type in types"
      ng-change="onTypeChange(question)">               
</select>
```

One of the ion-items:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item ng-repeat="answer in answers">
       <label ng-if="question.type == 1 || question.type == 4" 
              class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
          <span class="input-label">Ответ:</span>
          <input type="text" placeholder={{answer.answer}} ng-   model="answer.answer">
       </label>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

onTypeChange():

```
$scope.onTypeChange = function(question){
    var typeUpdateQuery = 'UPDATE `questions` SET "type" = "' + question.type.id + '" WHERE "id" = ' + question.id;
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, typeUpdateQuery).then(
        function(){
            $scope.answers=[];
            $scope.openQuestion();
            $state.reload();
        }, function (err){
            error(err);
        }
    );
}
```

`openQuestion` preloads the view's data just taking it from DB (fills in the `answers[]`), nothing special.

So, what should I do?

Comment: where is the `ng-if` and the `onTypeChange` function?

Comment: please add more code from your controller.. specifically the onTypeChange function.

Comment: added the `onTypeChange` and `ng-if` (misplaced it with 'ng-show' firstly)

Comment: thanks, can you clarify what you mean by "all I see is fields without ng-if"?

Comment: I have a field with question title, that shows without any conditions.
Instead of other fields with answers, there are just empty ion-items.

Comment: I was away for the weekend. I would have thought this was answered by now. Can I see you answers object? I also don't see the questions field, I am assuming it is right above the ionlist right? I am just making sure I get it.